# Sorting Input Numbers

Tags: java, if-statement

I am very new to Java and am trying to write an algorithm to take in three numbers and sort them as a way of practicing algorithm writing. Below is what I have.

```
package com.company;

public class Sort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int b = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        int c = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        int min, med, max;
    if(Math.max(a, b) == a){
        if(Math.max(a, c) == a){
            max=a;
            if(Math.max(b,c)==b){
                med=b;
                min=c;
            }else{
                med=c;
                min=b;
            }
        }else{
            max=c;
            med=a;
            min=b;
        }
    }else {
        if(Math.max(b,c)==b) {
            max = b;
            if(Math.max(a,c)==a) {
                med = a;
                min = c;
            }else {
                med = c;
                min = a;
            }
        }else{
            max=c;
            med=b;
            min=a;
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

When I attempt to call this file from the terminal like below I get the following error. What is causing the invalid flag error?

```
javac Sort.java 1 2 3
error: invalid flag: 1
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use --help for a list of possible options
```

Comment: what *line* is the traceback referring to.

Comment: Command-line input to your program belongs on the `java` command, not the `javac` command.

Comment: if you are trying to generate the java file class then use `javac` initially, but yes, for command-line args you need to use `java Sort` without the `.java` extension.

Comment: `javac Sort.java` followed by `java Sort 1 2 3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compile your code, you do ist with `javac Sort.java` in the console. As you can see, without parameter. In you want run the code, you do it with `java Sort 1 2 3`. Here you need to use the parameter.

Comment: When running it I actually had to do "java Sort.java 1 2 3", not sure if that's what you meant or not but it appears to be working now.

Answer (score 0):

Command-line arguments are passed when you're invoking the program. In Java, you compile the code with `javac` command and you invoke the program with `java` command. So, when you pass arguments when invoking the program, those arguments are passed to the `main` function.

The error you're seeing is from `javac`. `javac` is also a program that expects a java file to compile and some optional flags (for eg, to suppress warnings, etc). `javac` is not able to recognize `1` as a flag. just say `javac Sort.java` and it will compile your code. After that, run your program with `java` command, which itself is also a program that takes a class with optional arguments that are passed to the class while invoking it. So, call your program like `java Sort 123`

Answer (score 0):

**First compile your code as you compile any java code :**

`javac Sort.java`

**Now pass the command line arguments during run time :**

`java Sort 1 2 3`